# adding classif.imbalanced.rfsrc in mlr3

Tags: mlr3

First of all, many thanks to the guys  @mlr3!

The package randomForestSRC in R has a new function called imbalanced.rfsrc to help deal with class imbalance in classification. Will this learner be accessible in mlr3? imbalanced.rfsrc seems to work very well and also seems to implement state of the art approaches to dealing with class imbalance.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you open a learner request issue in mlr3extralearners and fill in the details then we'd be happy to consider adding this implementation!

https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3extralearners/issues/new?assignees=&labels=new+learner&template=learner-request-template.md&title=%5BLRNRQ%5D+Add+%3Calgorithm%3E+from+package+%3Cpackage%3E